# Trigger Workflow from Script Netsuite

Tags: javascript, workflow, netsuite, suitescript

Okay, I have decided to strip this one back to the bare bones based on the Netsuite documentation and go from there.

With the below in place I receive the following error still -

"Syntax error: missing : after property id"

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.0
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 */

require(['N/task'], 
function(task) {
var workflowTask = task.create({taskType: task.TaskType.WORKFLOW_TRIGGER});
workflowTask.recordType = 'customer';
workflowTask.recordId = 107;
workflowTask.workflowId = 3;
var taskId = workflowTask.submit();

return {
workflowTask};
});
```

Comment: Okay, I have decided to strip this one back to the bare bones based on the Netsuite documentation and go from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing the entry points for the UserEvent script.  I don't see something like

```
exports.beforeSubmit = beforeSubmit;
exports.beforeLoad = beforeLoad ;
exports.afterSubmit = afterSubmit ;

return exports;
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have had another thought. I am going to streamline the script down to the bare bones and work from there. Will post above under the original, if you are able to take a look?

Comment: You are still missing the entry points for a User Event script, you wont be able to use this as a User Event is that is your aim

Comment: Hi Rusty, thank you for coming back to me. I have changed direction with this script and added an afterSubmit functionality. But I am still have lots of trouble. If you get 2 minutes and you could check out this thread I would be very grateful
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72647681/rcrd-dsnt-exist-message-there-are-no-records-of-this-type
All I am trying to do is get a workflow on Item records to trigger when a goods receipt record is created. This is absorbing my every waking moment!